# Array getJSON by Index

Tags: jquery, json

I want to showing data like this:

```
Fire Forest : 60
Earthquake : 50
```

I've trying some method, but still get confused and showing not what I want. By the code below:

```
  $.getJSON(urlLink, function(data){
    var disasterData = '';

    $("#currentChartDisaster").empty();
    $("#currentChartDisaster").append("<h2>Jumlah Bencana Terjadi Bulan Ini</h2>");

    $.each(data,function(key, value){
      disasterData += '<h3>'+value+'</h3>';
    })
    $('#currentChartDisaster').append(disasterData);
  });
```

It's only showing like this :

```
Earthquake, Fire Forest. 60, 50
```

I have JSON format like this:

```
{
    "disasterName":[
      "Fire Forest",
      "Earthquake"
    ],
    "disasterCount":[
      "60",
      "50"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Right, so, if you convert an array to a string, it becomes a comma delimited string, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: BTW, your JSON data is not in a good format ("valid", yes - "usable", not really).   There's no association between name and count other than the index order, which you should not rely on (eg if you decide to start names alphabetically, which count goes with which name?).  Do you have the option to change the source data to make it more usable?

Comment: @freedomn-m yes, I have options to make it more usable. Actually, I just encode the data from Mysql naturally like that. But, I dont pretty much about SQL data. Can you tell me the right format and how to change it?

Comment: How you change the format of the JSON will depend on your data and how you generate it in the first place.  I suggest you create a new question which shows these things and keep this question for the UI output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the format of your data where the name/count are in separate arrays, you can use a basic `for` loop to get the index for each disaster, to get the corresponding name/count based on that index

```
    data.disasterName[i] + " : " + data.disasterCount[i]
```

This *assumes* there's the same number of disaster names as counts and that the associated values are in the same order - eg count[0] is for forest fires.

```js
var data = {
  "disasterName": [
    "Fire Forest",
    "Earthquake"
  ],
  "disasterCount": [
    "60",
    "50"
  ]
};

var count = data.disasterName.length;

var html = '';
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  html += "<h3>" + data.disasterName[i] + " : " + data.disasterCount[i] + "</h3>";
}
$("#output").append(html);
```

```css
h3 { font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```

---

As you can change the format, you could make it more object-like, eg an array of:

```
    {
      "name": "Forest Fire",
      "count": 60
    },
```

then the js will be closer to your initial attempt as you don't need to loop the index and can use a .forEach() or .map()

```js
var data = {
  "disasters": [
    {
      "name": "Forest Fire",
      "count": 60
    },
    {
      "name": "Earthquake",
      "count": 50
    }
  ]
};


// forEach
//var html = '';
//data.disasters.forEach(disaster => {
//  html += "<h3>" + disaster.name + " : " + disaster.count + "</h3>";
//});
// or map

var html = data.disasters.map(disaster =>
  "<h3>" + disaster.name + " : " + disaster.count + "</h3>"
);


$("#output").append(html);
```

```css
h3 { font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, it works well. JSON has been reformatted and the data showing as it should be